# SQL Help - Counting rows from two tables

Tags: sql, count

I have 2 tables: products & category

I'm trying to write the sql to count the number of products per category. So far I have this:

```
SELECT `name`, count(*) as `size`
FROM products
INNER JOIN category ON category.`id` = products.`categoryID`
GROUP BY category.`name`
```

This will return me a list of each category name and the number of products for that category. However it doesn't list categories that have 0 products. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a right join.

```
SELECT `name`, count(*) as `size`
FROM products
RIGHT JOIN category ON category.`id` = products.`categoryID`
GROUP BY category.`name`
```

Comment: Nice! Thank worked, problem is its showing a count of 1 when it should be 0?

Comment: count(*) is giving you the number of rows. If you want the number of products use count(products.categoryID). At least I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT `name`, count(products.id) as `size`
FROM category
LEFT JOIN products ON category.`id` = products.`categoryID`
GROUP BY category.`name`
```

Comment: No luck, same problem occurs. I think it has something to do with how the inner join is working i.e its skipping categories that are not associated with any products. I have tried changing around the inner join to no avail.

Comment: Oh, that is right - I changed the query, so the first table is `category`, and the `JOIN` to be `INNER JOIN`, so that categories without products should appear now